# i want to update state field but drop down (State field) is not updating but other fields are updating. codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

[Here is code of field state that i want to update, i am new and i really appreciate you  ]

```
<div class="">
                        <label class="control-label" >State</label>
                        <select name="state_id" class="form-control col-sm-5" >
                            <option value="" >Select State...</option>
                            <?php foreach ($all_state as $v_state) : ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $v_state->state_id ?>" <?php
                                if (!empty($employee_info->state_id)) {
                                    echo $v_state->state_id == $employee_info->state_id ? 'selected' : '';
                                }
                                ?>><?php echo $v_state->name ?></option>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select> 
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this my be help you..

```
          <label class="control-label" >State</label>
                    <select name="state_id" class="form-control col-sm-5" >
                     <option value="" >Select State...</option>
                    <?php foreach ($all_state as $v_state) : ?> 
                      <option value="<?php echo $v_state->state_id ?>" <?php  if($v_state->state_id == $employee_info->state_id){echo "selected";}?>> <?php echo $v_state->name; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

```
<div class="">
    <label class="control-label" >State</label>
    <select name="state_id" class="form-control col-sm-5" >
        <option value="" >Select State...</option>
        <?php foreach ($all_state as $v_state) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $v_state->state_id ?>" 
                        <?php 
                        if (!empty($employee_info->state_id) && ($v_state->state_id == $employee_info->state_id)):
                            echo  'selected';
                        endif;
                        ?>>
                    <?php echo $v_state->name ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: it is helping me can you suggest me another solution

Comment: It is best way to set selected value in drop-down. so apply this solution for your problem.

Comment: sorry Nikunj Rathod this solution is giving me a blank page i don't know why?